# Does a processor affinity set by SetThreadAffinityMask also apply to children threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows-7, windows-10, affinity

I have an application that makes use of many threads, one of them being more time critical than the others.  I have already tried using priority, but have found that Windows doesn't always honor the priority to the extent I would like and sometimes allows lessor priority threads to block my critical thread for long periods (50+ milliseconds).  To resolve this, I'm thinking of setting a processor affinity for each thread to limit the non-critical ones such that they can't use some cores (say cores #1 and #2) and the critical thread will always have those cores (#1 and #2) available.

My question is, if I set a processor affinity mask to my entry-point thread via [SetThreadAffinityMask()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask), do subsequent threads created by this initial thread inherit the affinity mask?  Or do I need to manually set the affinity each and every time I spawn a thread throughout the system?

Comment: From the documentation it doesn't seem that the affinity mask is inherited from the thread. But looks like [SetProcessAffinityMask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setprocessaffinitymask) would do for you?

Comment: @SergeyA "*looks like SetProcessAffinityMask would do for you?*" - not if he wants some threads only on cores 1-2, and the rest of the threads on cores 3+. Calling `SetThreadAffinityMask()` for every thread would be the right way to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the thread affinity is NOT inherited when creating a thread using std::thread with VS2015 on Windows 10.